# I am trying to get the text to appear on the right hand side of the image, and for the actual image box to be a lot slimmer that it currently is

Tags: html, css

This is the css I have atm but it is all going chaotic and this is how the section of the page looks:
[![

```css
#firstborder{
    border:  #3063A5; 
    border-style: double; 
    font-size: 9.5px;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", serif;
    padding-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}


.linguistics_paragraph{
    margin-left: 385px;
    padding: 3px; margin-top: 5px;
    top: 40px; 
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", serif;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z427K.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z427K.png)

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0):

To make the image box slimmer I would suggest using the max-width property and setting it to your desired width so it never gets any bigger than that.

I can make a code snippet but as far as your text issue, are you trying to get the text within the bordered box? Also what is your desired outcome for the legend?

Comment: I have managed to get the text to the right hand side of the legend box however none of that is responsive so if I change the browser size (min-width 510px and max-width 960px) the everything becomes jumbled up.

Comment: Gotcha so your desired layout is the map image and the legend on the left and the text on the right, and also to have it responsive then? But with the left side much thinner than it is now?

Comment: Pretty much yeah; it's been a headache trying to get it to work and I am not sure what is preventing it from a) being responsive and b) having text to the right of the legend box.

Comment: Okay so I would do something like this then which I believe will give you your desired layout and will also be responsive. https://jsfiddle.net/pucog6e2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer this question on a conceptual basis as you don't have your HTML provided

So as you said everything gets messy when you change the width of the browser therefore
we have to first work on making it responsive. So just go to your Html file and make a **div wrapper or container** that would hold both of your **image and the paragraph tags** 
for example, something that would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="files/exampleimg.png" id="pic">
   <p id="text">This is something</p>
</div>
```

Now in your CSS file remove the margin-left or margin-right you used to position the image and the paragraph tags and use flex or grid or anything similar to make it responsively positioned, I'm gonna go with flex so here it goes:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /*putting img to left and paragraph to right*/
}

#pic {
  padding-left: 50px; /*as per your requirement*/
}
#text {
  padding-right: 50px; /*as per your requirement*/
}
```

and that's pretty much it for the responsive part, all we have to do now is make the image box slimmer, so for that do this:

```
#firstborder{
  border: 1px solid #707070; /*this would make it slimmer but play with it to find out what suits best*/
}
```

you change the 1px to 4 px its gonna get thicker and you crank it down and it would get slimmer, there you go, now you have a responsive page and your image-box slimmed up.

and oh for your legend part add this to your HTML

```
<img src="files/legend.png" id="legend">
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative; /*binding up the legend with container*/
}

#legend {
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: absolute; /*stiching the legend to that pic*/
    top: 40px; /*as per your requirement*/
}
```